# How long are sterilised bottles sterile for? And is there a way to keep them sterile for longer?

Tags: newborn, bottle-feeding

I plan to go to an all day event 10am - 8pm and won't be able to sterilise bottles during the day. If I sterilise them in the morning, how long will I be able to use them for? If I put them in the fridge at the event, will they be considered sterile for longer? My baby will be 4 weeks old for this, if that makes a difference.

edit: to clarify, I am planning on taking empty bottles and filling them up from cartons when I am there. So I am talking about just the bottles, the milk is not a problem.

Comment: Are you asking if you can take bottles of milk to the event, or take empty bottles to fill at the event?

Answer (score 2):

If you take empty sterilised bottles, they will be good for the entire day given the following conditions:

- after sterilising bottles, teats and caps, close the bottles, and put the cap over the teat
- store the bottles in a clean bag
- after feeding, store the used bottles in  a separate compartment

In reality, they should be perfectly healthy for babies over a longer timespan than this, but taking extra care with a 4 week old is never a bad idea so stick to a one day maximum.